# linux: How can I view all UUIDs for all available disks on my system?

Tags: linux, storage

My `/etc/fstab` contains this:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=77d8da74-a690-481a-86d5-9beab5a8e842 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

There are several other disks on this system, and not all disks are being mounted to the correct location (For example, /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 are sometimes reversed).

How can I see the UUIDs for all disks on my system? Can I see the UUID for the third disk on this system?

Comment: @setzamora answer is better. Please change accepted answer.

Comment: Related: *[What is UUID, PARTUUID and PTUUID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375548/what-is-uuid-partuuid-and-ptuuid)*

Answer (score 235, accepted):

In `/dev/disk/by-uuid` there are symlinks mapping each drive's UUID to its entry in `/dev` (e.g. `/dev/sda1`)

You can view these with the command `ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid`

Comment: It's not readable when LVM partitions.

Comment: LVM already uses long UUID-like identifiers (although presented differently) in its structure. I think the only reason for using filesystem UUIDs with LVM would be as an unified interface for some sort of automation, as LVM already does the mapping of LVs to human-friendly names for you.

Comment: Just for reference, the result has changed and will be different from `blkid` and won't work for booting: https://i.imgur.com/ocgoi3g.png

Comment: I often use this approach, especially becuase blkid needs SU privileges. But `/dev/disk/by-uuid` unfortunately has much less information and it will get you into trouble for some cases. For me this was working with RAID and btrfs volumes as different partitions share a uuid, but there is only one entry for each UUID in the symlinks...

Comment: This does not work on all linux

Answer (score 269):

There's a tool called `blkid` (use it as root or with `sudo`),

```
# blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: LABEL="/" UUID="ee7cf0a0-1922-401b-a1ae-6ec9261484c0" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3"
```

you can check [this link](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/short-tip-get-uuid-of-hard-disks/) for more info

Comment: I like blkid, especially when LVM2.

Comment: Just a minor comment: looks like being a member of group `disk` is sufficient to run `blkid`; no need for full superuser privileges.

Comment: If you want *only* the UUID (like for parsing in a script), you can do `blkid /dev/sda1 -s UUID -o value`.

Comment: Quick comment here : in my distro (Debian 8) this yields UUID as well as "PARTUUID", which is rather confusing. I used {lsblk} commands which gives only one value.

Comment: This one saves a great deal of time, though I prefer to do `blkid /dev/sd*` to list all drives.. The info that spits out is generally more than enough to find the drive you need. :)

Comment: PARTUUID for GPT-partitioned disks is the GPT UUID for the partition, not for the filesystem in it. Might be useful when a filesystem is not created yet. On a MBR-partitioned disk, PARTUUID is not a real UUID, but simply a Windows Disk Signature from the MBR + a dash + partition number.

Comment: @arielf Apparently I'm *not* in this "disk" group and had to run sudo to get it to work!  So users *may* need superuser privs (LUbuntu 18.04)

Comment: @Michael if you can `sudo` & are not further restricted, you may add your username to any group: edit `/etc/group`, by (e.g. if you use `vi`) `sudo vipw -g`.  This approach is generally better than always running as root. You will need to re-login to be included in recently added groups (use the `id` command to see which groups you're in)

Comment: @takumar The PARTUUID is often more useful. Besides the reasons mentioned by telcoM above, you will also need it when you migrate the filesystem from one partition to another because they will get the same filesystem UUID. PARTUUID will always be there and never collide on one GPT.

Comment: this is to list partitions not physical disks.

Answer (score 103):

The best command to use is 
`lsblk -f`.
It will list all the devices and partitions, how they are mounted (if at all) and the tree structure of the devices in the case of using LVM, crypto_LUKS,  or multiple volume groups on the same drive.

Comment: This is the best answer - the most thorough, and a truly one-stop method.

Comment: An addition: I had to put sudo in front of this, otherwise it was unable to get the UUID of the partition and the column was empty.

Comment: `df --output=source MYFILE | tail -n1 | xargs lsblk -o uuid`

Comment: I like this answer best - its a nice output

Comment: For me, from an arch linux minimal boot disk, this does show a pretty tree with free space and mount points but no UUIDs, even when i add "-o UUID"

Comment: this worked for me when looking up the mdadm array.

Answer (score 27):

To only get the `UUID` of a specific disk device (for example to be used in a script) you can use:

```
sudo blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdXY
```

where `/dev/sdXY` is the name of the device.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the top comment.

Comment: @fideloper it can't see logical volumes.

Answer (score 17):

```
lsblk -o +uuid,name
```

You can see all the outputs that can be added to the `-o` (`--output`) with

```
lsblk --help
```

Also this will do the job

```
# blkid
```

Comment: Isn't `name` printed by default ?

Comment: it is. Added it just for educational purposes (add the comma to separate the fields you want)

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

```
ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

If you want to check what type the partition is, use:

```
df -Th
```

and it will show you if you have ext3 or ext2. Today it helped me because there was a formatted ext2 partition and I thought it was ext3, which was causing the mount to fail.

Comment: You could always try `mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /media/sda1`.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers do not work for multiple devices or for devices with identical UUIDs.

Try this:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sd*
```

Comment: A universally unique identifier (UUID) should always be unique. The entire purpose of a UUID is to be a unique, universally. If not, there's a problem. I have seen duplicated UUIDs in cloned VMs, at least for network devices.

Comment: If you clone a partition with the `dd` command the copy will have the same uuid and yes, that is a problem. The other answers here wouldn't show that.

Answer (score 1):

With the following command line you can see UUID plus the mapping to partitions.

```
ls /dev/disk/by-uuid -lt

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  1 18:51 57eacf4e-1940-436e-b945-85f8d4833aa5 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  1 18:51 656f4cae-8527-43a0-a80f-00ac82818744 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  1 18:51 d627595d-4060-440e-8380-a1fe9f3f2a81 -> ../../md0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  1 18:51 0dfd6dfe-1852-460d-852c-676a5b9035ed -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  1 18:51 b1ddf850-8f81-429f-a653-38ae4a4ebb6f -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  1 18:51 b4b729f7-5699-411c-8f5a-424bbc7c89fc -> ../../sdb
```

Comment: Why can we see the uuid of sda

Comment: There is one UUID for a file system per partition. On sda, i have 4 partitions so, I had 4 UUID. https://wiki.debian.org/Part-UUID

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you:
renaming by kernel of `/dev/sd**` after a reboot:

Of course all my automatic mounting in `/etc/fstab` are referenced by LABEL or by UUID, so basically there is no problem for that.
And all the commands above ,blkid or lsblk, give this kind of information.

But the trouble begins as in my case, when you are using  partition in RAW mode, in the currently booted system point-of-view:
for example either:
the partition is used as raw device, to make a virtual disk for VirtualBox
(so the reference to this partition is something like: `/dev/sdf3`)
or
the partition is used as raw device, to make a LUN for iSCSI
(so the reference to this partition is something like: `/dev/sdc6`)

So now at boot , for example in rc.local, you have to find in a reliable manner, what is the `/dev/sdXX` device of your dedicated RAW partition, and adapt some file:

**EXAMPLE 1**

The VirtualBox disk *.vmk description of this raw disk, in the part something like:

```
\# Extent description
RW 488397167 FLAT "/dev/sdXX" 0
```

and then restart the VirtualBox service

**EXAMPLE 2**

in tgtd configuration, a target :target0 was associated to `/dev/sdd6` at build time.
After reboot you get the same partition renamed `/deb/sdc6`
This happens with a removable disk, USB or eSATA!
So how to find the new device automatically ?
Again in /etc/rc.d/rc.local

So in this case we need a reliable manner to find what is the new device name.
GPT partition offers unique GUID for any GPT partition, written in GPT table.

gdisk does not provide this info with listing mode, but only in interactive mode with: i command. Fortunately, blkid does it!

So you need to write a shell script, to look in all your disks, which is the device `/dev/sdXX`, associated to the GUID noticed at partition creation time.

Something like, search_device_by_partUUID.sh:

```
\#!/bin/bash

PART_UUID=$1
if [ "$PART_UUID" = "" ]
then
    echo "Syntax: $0 <a valid partition UUID>"
    exit 3
fi
lsblk | grep '^sd' | awk '{print $1}' | while read DISK_DEVICE
do 
    INFO=`blkid /dev/${DISK_DEVICE}* | grep "PARTUUID=\"$PART_UUID\"" `
    if [ "$INFO" != "" ]
    then
        echo INFO : "$INFO"
        BLK_DEVICE=`echo "$INFO" | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo $BLK_DEVICE > /dev/shm/blkdevice
        echo -n "BLK_DEVICE : " ; cat /dev/shm/blkdevice
    fi
done
```

and then use `/dev/shm/blkdevice`, in your rc.local script.

Answer (score 0):

To see the uuid of a hard disk partition I just boot the system up with a Linux CD and goto my computer mount, click on, the partition I want to see. 
The uuid number of the Linux partition will be displayed.

You can also see disk uuid by running Linux Disk utility after the Linux CD boot up.

Comment: What's "my computer mount"? And what's "Linux Disk utility", sounds like gnome-disk-utility aka Disks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check /dev/disk/by-partuuid in these cases. there are symlinks mapping each drive's PARTUUID to its entry in /dev/sdb1 etc

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/a/1116758/969454

```bash
sudo grep swap /etc/fstab
## Output like:
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
# UUID=34e3f31b-16ec-4c84-8f4d-339f38d04a3b none swap sw 0 0

sudo lsblk -f -l| grep SWAP
## Output like:
sda6 swap 34e3f31b-16ec-4c84-8f4d-339f38d04a3b [SWAP]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).