# What is UUID, PARTUUID and PTUUID?

Tags: fstab, gpt

In the [`blkid`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) output, some lines contain UUID and PARTUUID pairs and others only PTUUID. What do they mean?

In particular, why are two IDs required for a partition and why are some partitions identified by UUID/PARTUUID and some by PTUUID?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.25/libblkid-docs/libblkid-Partitions-probing.html#libblkid-Partitions-probing.description

Comment: @don_crissti I've seen that page in Google, but it doesn't explain anything.

Comment: What kind of "explanation" do you need, other than the _description_ of `PTUUID` and `PART_ENTRY_UUID` (aka `PARTUUID`) ?

Comment: PARTUUID identifies a GPT partition (like /dev/sdbX). UUID identifies a filesystem. Not sure about PTUUID.. Maybe identifies a GPT device (like /dev/sdX)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`UUID` is a *filesystem-level* UUID, which is retrieved from the filesystem metadata inside the partition. It can only be read if the filesystem type is known and readable.

`PARTUUID` is a *partition-table-level* UUID for the partition, a standard feature for all partitions on GPT-partitioned disks. Since it is retrieved from the partition table, it is accessible without making any assumptions at all about the actual contents of the partition. If the partition is encrypted using some unknown encryption method, this might be the only accessible unique identifier for that particular partition.

`PTUUID` is the UUID of the partition table itself, a unique identifier for the entire disk assigned at the time the disk was partitioned. It is the equivalent of the *disk signature* on MBR-partitioned disks but with more bits and a standardized procedure for its generation.

On MBR-partitioned disks, there are no UUIDs in the partition table. The 32-bit *disk signature* is used in place of a `PTUUID`, and `PARTUUID`s are created by adding a dash and a two-digit partition number to the end of the disk signature.

Comment: Can that `PARTUUID` be used in e.g. /etc/fstab like `UUID`?

Comment: @jarno According to `man fstab` on my Debian 10 system, yes. If you use a different distribution, check the man page on *your* system to verify.

Comment: Here it also says that "Note that mount(8) uses UUIDs as strings. The string representation of the UUID should be based on lower case characters." However, at least in one case also capital letters seem to work.

Comment: Is it possible to change or replace PTUUID and PARTUUID using `dd`?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub It's technically possible, but *very* awkward to do, since you must calculate the location of each PTUUID and also recalculate and replace a CRC32 checksum after making a change. It'll be much easier to use the expert commands of `fdisk` that is of a recent enough version to support GPT partitioning: `x` then `i` to change PTUUID, or `x` then `u` to change PARTUUID of a specific partition.