# ZFS, mounted on what disk/partition

Tags: zfs

A ZFS is mounted in my system on `/mnt/zfs`.

`zfs list` prints:

```
NAME          USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
my-zfs-pool   523G   376G      523G  /mnt/zfs
```

I.e. this is the ZFS pool `my-zfs-pool`.

`zpool status` prints:

```
  pool: my-zfs-pool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:15:03 with 0 errors on Sun Jul 12 00:39:04 2020
config:

        NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        my-zfs-pool                             ONLINE       0     0     0
          791b9bbf-a779-2a49-8648-08461ec13df7  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

`lsblk -f` lists:

```
NAME        FSTYPE     LABEL             UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
...
sda                                                                                          
└─sda1      zfs_member my-zfs-pool       4642836688446740704                                 
...
```

So there I found a ZFS partition with a label `my-zfs-pool`, so I assume `/mnt/zfs` is mounted from `sda1`. But how do I really know?

What exactly is this identifier `791b9bbf-a779-2a49-8648-08461ec13df7`? Is this an partition UUID? I cannot really find it anywhere else. The UUID of `sda1` is different.

Compared to other such output from other people, e.g. [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/3o7e56/what_exactly_is_a_vdev/), it prints sth like `ada0p3` or `wwn-0x50014ee20b8b7ba0-part3`, i.e. the identifier of the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just looked badly. Under `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/`, I find `791b9bbf-a779-2a49-8648-08461ec13df7`.

Now I just wonder, when this vdev / physical dev (on the partition) was created, was it a bad choice to use the partuuid as identifier? Should I have used the UUID instead?

The difference of PARTUUID vs UUID is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/463410/2954):

> `UUID` is a *filesystem-level* UUID, which is retrieved from the filesystem metadata inside the partition. It can only be read if the filesystem type is known and readable.
>
> `PARTUUID` is a *partition-table-level* UUID for the partition, a standard feature for all partitions on GPT-partitioned disks. Since it is retrieved from the partition table, ...

So it sounds like `PARTUUID` is probably a good choice.

`lsblk --output NAME,PARTUUID,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID,SIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda` shows:

```
NAME   PARTUUID                             FSTYPE     LABEL       UUID                                   SIZE FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                                     931,5G                
└─sda1 791b9bbf-a779-2a49-8648-08461ec13df7 zfs_member my-zfs-pool 4642836688446740704                  931,5G
```

How can I make `lsblk` show the ZFS mount point (`/mnt/zfs`)?