# Is there a way to retrieve UUID information of an unmounted hard drive?

Tags: linux, centos

I have an unmounted and unpartitioned hard drive and I need to get it's UUID. Is there a way to retrieve the UUID of this hard drive?

Running the command lsblk just gets me the information below
[image]

In the disk utility program, this is all that it shows for the /dev/sdb hard drive(yes it says sdc, took the wrong screenshot but sdb shows the same thing)

[image]

Do I have to mount it or create a partition just to obtain the UUID of the hardrive at /dev/sdb?

Answer (score 6):

Running [blkid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html) like this

```
sudo blkid -o list
```

will provide its UUID.

Comment: it only list a UUID for the hdds that are already mounted, the field is empty for the unmounted hard drives such as /dev/sdb

Comment: My bad, sorry. sudo blkid -o list

Answer (score 4):

> unmounted and unpartitioned hard drive and I need to get it's UUID

UUID is a property of filesystem or format, unformatted hard drives don't have UUIDs. You can get PARTUUID for partitions and PTUUID for partition tables, [see this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375548/what-is-uuid-partuuid-and-ptuuid), but that also doesn't apply for an empty disk.

Unique identifier for disks is [WWID/WWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name) provided by the disk itself. You can get it either from sysfs

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/device/wwid 
naa.5002538e40aa0206
```

or from a symlink in `/dev/disk/by-id`

```
$ ls -la /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Mar 10 07:21 wwn-0x5002538e40aa0206 -> ../../sda
```

or UDev (which is in charge of creating the symlink)

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sda | grep ID_WWN
E: ID_WWN=0x5002538e40aa0206
E: ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x5002538e40aa0206
```

Comment: Or `/usr/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -x /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 0):

`blkid` should work with unmounted disks, but you must make sure that the disk is formatted.

List disks:

```bash
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1,7T  0 disk
sdb      8:16   0  300G  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0   64G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0   63G  0 part /
├─sdc2   8:34   0    1K  0 part
└─sdc5   8:37   0  975M  0 part [SWAP]
```

Before format:

```bash
$ blkid -o list
device                       fs_type     label        mount point                      UUID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdc1                    ext4                     /                                9c49994f-6ffd-496a-945b-85e3b04a84ef
/dev/sdc5                    swap                     [SWAP]                           f14ea985-e1e6-43a8-ba09-12a273604c96
```

Note: `/dev/sdb` is not shown.

Format disk with ext4:

```bash
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 78643200 4k blocks and 19660800 inodes
Filesystem UUID: d4b71992-fbc3-4263-b974-e5933a1ebfe4
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Now running `blkid` again:

```bash
$ blkid -o list
device                                          fs_type         label            mount point                                         UUID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sdc1                                       ext4                             /                                                   9c49994f-6ffd-496a-945b-85e3b04a84ef
/dev/sdc5                                       swap                             [SWAP]                                              f14ea985-e1e6-43a8-ba09-12a273604c96
/dev/sdb                                        ext4                             (not mounted)                                       d4b71992-fbc3-4263-b974-e5933a1ebfe4
```