# How can you determine which EFI System Partition was used to boot a Linux System?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, uefi

If you have a system with multiple disks and multiple EFI System Partitions how can you determine which one was used to boot the Linux system once the system is booted if they both end up booting the same kernel and root partition?

Comment: Please add more details starting with `fdisk -l` output.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310). For the record: [the same question on SU](https://superuser.com/q/1669471/432690).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply run `sudo efibootmgr -v` and see which boot entry has been used to boot the system. You'll see something like `HD(1,GPT,PARTUUID)` and the PARTUUID is what you're looking for.

You can use `blkid` or `sfdisk -d /dev/device` to see your partitions PARTUUIDs.

( There are lots of UUIDs, not to be confused: [What is UUID, PARTUUID and PTUUID?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375548/what-is-uuid-partuuid-and-ptuuid) )

Thanks, telcoM, for correcting me.

Comment: On my system, I have boot options referring to two different disks, both beginning with `HD(1,GPT`. So it seems the number is not reliable. Instead, you should pay attention to the GUID specified after `GPT`. This will exactly match the partition unique UUID in the GPT partition table, viewable with commands `lsblk -o +partuuid` or `blkid`. Section 3.1.2 of the UEFI spec v2.9 says: "The boot manager must use the GUID or or signature and partition number in the hard drive device path to match it to a device in the system." So the GUID would be the primary identifier, not the disk number.